# Error in regular expression using replaceAll

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to replace a String like this:

```
ABCDEF|1.0/nAAAAAA|1.2/n
```

For something like this, in the case the string ABCDEF exists:

```
ABCDEF|1.1/nAAAAAA|1.2/n
```

I'm trying so with this regular expression, being key the `ABCDEF` string and `totalDifference` the equivalent to `1.1`, but it doesn't work:

```
text= text.replaceAll(key+"(|.*/n)", key+"|"+totalDifference+"/n");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear: are you just trying to extract `1.1` and `1.2` (the numbers after the `|`) or is there something else? `key + \|([\d.]+)` ?

Comment: @David542, I'm trying to change the 1.0 for 1.1, what I mean is that the regular expression should go to the part of the String where the string "ABCDEF" is, then change the number after that string and the | to another one and leave the rest of the String as it was.

Comment: What about: `ABCDEF\|([\d.]+)`. See: https://gyazo.com/1e30a5a47682914a62b19344d560b1e3

Comment: updated my answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case if this helps, one of the things here is that `|` is not escaped and that `.*` is too generic, if you narrow it down just a little bit, it works. In this case I assumed you want to replace the decimal number in that place and it works like this.

```
str.replaceAll(key + "(\\|[\\d.]*)", key + "|" + totalDifference)
```

If you change your code just to escape `|` you'll see that now whole string is matched because of `.*\n` which matches everything until the end of the string, then you specify that you want only digits or dots in those places with `[\\d.]*` and voila!

Answer (score 3):

If key is `ABCDEF` and you are trying to extract the exactly two numbers in the line of text if that key exists, you should be able to do something like this:

```
// Using "ABCDEF" as key
ABCDEF\|(?:([\d.]+)[^|]+)\|([\d.]+)
```

[image]

If you're just looking to modify the first number with `1.1` you can use `ABCDEF\|([\d.]+)` with a substitution, shown below:

[image]

You can play around with it here: https://regex101.com/r/hHjQJe/1.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the pipe to match it literally `\|`, you can omit the capture group for a match only you can make the quantifier non greedy.

```
ABCDEF\|.*?/n
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cSp9hN/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/h1Dei8)

```
String text = "ABCDEF|1.0/nAAAAAA|1.2/n";
String totalDifference = "1.1";
String key = "ABCDEF";
text = text.replaceAll(key+"ABCDEF\\|.*?/n", key+"|"+totalDifference+"/n");
System.out.println(text);
```

Output

```
ABCDEF|1.0/nAAAAAA|1.2/n
```

---

A bit more strict pattern could be to match digits with an optional decimal part

```
ABCDEF\|\d+(?:\.\d+)?/n
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KyDEeJ/1)